# macro-like function as filter in postgresql

Tags: function, postgresql, database, stored-functions

I have a table with some RDF statements inside, like `Quads(graph, subject, verb, object)` and I find myself doing queries like:

```
select * from quads where verb = 'rdf:type' and object = 'smtg:Type'
select * from quads where verb = 'rdf:label' and object = 'bla bla'
```

I would like to express this in a form like

```
select * from quads where type('smtg:Type')
select * from quads where label('bla bla')
```

While this seems a "trivial" text substitution, I have no idea of how and if this would be implementable in postgresql, though I sort of expect this to be impossible.

To the best of my knowledge I can use a function to hardcode the constants, and do

```
select * from quads where rdftype() = verb and object = 'smtg:Type'
```

or I can use a function as the `from` argument like

```
select * from typed('smtg:Type')
```

sadly, the former is quite verbose, and the latter does not seem to be amendable to combination e.g. I can't do an hypothetical

```
select * from quads where type('smtg:Type') and inGraph('mygraph')
```

Is there a way to do what I want? It seems impossible, but I wonder if there is a way.

**EDIT**: a sqlfiddle instance: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!1/40b2c/3 .

To be more clear, the reason why this seems unfeasible is that the macro-ish function would be returning a boolean (it is used in the `where` clause, as if it where a `select $1=somevalue`) but using an "implicit" row argument in which it would access multiple fields at once, and I have not seen such an example in the pg docs.

Comment: I don't see a reason why this couldn't be done in a PL/pgSQL function. But to be sure we would need more information. Please post the exact table structure (as `create table...`) and some sample data (as `insert into ...`)  you might post a working copy with your first two statements at http://sqlfiddle.com

Comment: If `verb` is functionally dependent on `object`, then you should remove the redundant column and normalize your schema. The additional condition on `verb` would be redundant next to the one on `object`. If `verb` can *not* be deduced from `object`, then it is still unclear how you resolve `type('#Person')`. Generally, you can do almost *anything* in plpgsql. When you run into an problem that cannot be solved with plain SQL, generate *dynamic SQL* inside a plpgsql function. Search for `[plpgsql] EXECUTE` or `dynamic-sql` here on SO for more.

Comment: `verb` is not functionally dependent on object. I don't understand what you mean by "resolve", I'm sorry, but,  `type('#Person')` would be equivalent to a `verb_and_object_equals_to('type', '#Person')`with one argument fixed.

Answer (score 3):

> and the latter [function] does not seem to be amendable to combination e.g. I
>   can't do an hypothetical

As long as the return type is stable, you can do pretty much anything in a plpgsql function.

You did not disclose how to resolve `type('smtg:Type')` or `inGraph('mygraph')` - are these supposed to be functions? Returning .. what?
But for a simple case like this even a plain SQL function should do the job:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION f_foo (_type text, _graph text DEFAULT NULL)
  RETURNS SETOF quads AS
$func$
   SELECT *
   FROM   quads
   WHERE  CASE WHEN $1 IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END
   AND    CASE WHEN $2 IS NOT NULL THEN ... ELSE ... END
   ORDER  BY ...;
$func$  LANGUAGE sql;
```

In PostgreSQL 9.2 or later you can also use parameter names instead of positional parameters (`$1`, `$2`, ..) in SQL functions.

Call:

Since I defined a DEFAULT for the second parameter, you can call this function with one *or* two parameters:

```
SELECT * FROM f_foo('smtg:Type');
```

Or:

```
SELECT * FROM f_foo('smtg:Type', 'mygraph');
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, I have updated the question with some more detail with what the arguments/return values are. A set/table returning function seems, as I wrote, not composable, I basically have to pre-write every possible combination of predicates in it.